# How to make plugin work in each template in wordpress

Tags: plugins, images, templates, hooks

I am new to plugin development .I want to get all images of a particular page/post and want to show them as slideshow below the page ..Currently i am able to gather all images in media library and display it...But i want images if that particular page ..I have learnt that to get images of particular template u need to add lines of code in that specific post template ..But how that can be done using a plugin

```
    $query_images_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
        $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
    }
foreach($images as $item){

   /// any function not yet decided
}
echo($item);
```

I m getting image urls in $item ..

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put your code in your question into a function. Maybe something like `function wpse_91897_get_image() { }`. Then try the code below. I haven't tested this but it should work.

```
function wpse_91897_display($content) {
    global $single;

    $output = wpse_91897_get_image();

    if (is_single()) {
        return $content . $output;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Then you would add a filter to call the functions for the content.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_91897_display');
```

Then add some CSS to position and style it. It will show up under the content on your post.

Comment: Thanks @pat for your reply..But i m able to get images from post content and also add them my style but the prob is how wud i place in the post content again back to its original postion with my manipulation on images..